# OpenSSL Broadcast all clients that are connected C

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I been busy with openssl and C under Microsoft, currently I got the multithreaded server and clients that communicate through SSL on a TCP/IP socket. "Took me some while to read all the documents / manuals from Openssl" but hey you learn at least something.

Now I want the server to broadcast a message to all clients that are connected. I can't find any information on the internet how to accomplish this, everything for me is a bit to vague or not documented that great.

If anyone of you can provide me an Manual or anything that is related to broadcast to clients, that would be very helpful.

It doesn't have to be for microsoft, Linux / unix or anything that can pinpoint me in the right way would be awesome.

Comment: There's no one right way, it completely depends on the design of the rest of your program and your I/O model. For example, the solutions are completely different if you're using one thread and an event loop than they are if you're using a thread per client.

Comment: Forgot to mention every client has his own Thread ;) updating the questing

Comment: SSL/TLS relies on TCP stream ( for retransmissions and ordering ) so it is from one source to one destination. there is DTLS to have tls over UDP but i don't know if it is even possible to have mutlicast/broadcast with it. But since you have as many threads as client, your broadcast will then be an applicative broadcast, ie you will copy the same information to be sent for each and every client. I doubt that anything at socket/OpenSsl BIO can help you at a lower level.

Comment: @KittyKris Then your question is basically, "I have a bunch of threads, how can I get them all to do something?".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes thats what i want to archive. the OpenSSL library is soo vague, and the examples are to low to find something what I want to fix. but if its not doable i will figure out something else to encrypt my data.

Comment: @philippelhardy yes i think OpenSSL/BIO is not able to send towards clients that are connected even tried to bind an SSL* to every client but still the program crashes

Comment: i would suggest you first try to implement your server and client with basic socket without ssl ( ease further testings ) then add ssl on top of it once it is working in clear.

Comment: @KittyKris Your question really has nothing to do with SSL. That your threads will react to the broadcast command by sending data over an SSL connection has nothing to do with how you tell the threads that you need them to broadcast.

Comment: I tried to post my stuff but wtf i have to add 8 spaces aka as 4 tabs here on every line ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL won't help you do that (i.e. broadcasting), either with or without TLS layer your problem is the same as broadcasting an information over multiple TCP sockets. I don't see any other way than to send the very same information on all clients.

Comment: Vague answer, could u pin point me how i get something going to send to multiple clients ?

Comment: show me your code, i could then provide a less vague answer.

Comment: Well its a simple chat server P2P currently, just the normal stuff. 

The SSL works ok while Peer to server. 

No i just want to broadcast a message like " hey dude we gonna restart the server " 

It's not UDP or anything like that 

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

TCP have no concept of broadcasting.  Whatever data you want to "broadcast" has to be manually sent to every individual TCP connection that you have established.  The fact that you are using OpenSSL is irrelevant, as broadcasting has nothing to do with SSL/TLS itself.  You would have to keep track of the connected clients, and then loop through them when needed sending your broadcast data to each client one at time, the same way you would send any other data, SSL/TLS or otherwise.

Comment: No i mentioned i want to broadcast a SendToAll clients on the tcp/ip stream not UDP or anything like that ;)

Comment: What I said still stands. There is no such thing as broadcasting in TCP.  You have to send your broadcast data to each connected TCP client one at a time yourself.

Comment: Its not "broadcast protocol" its not using 255.255.255.255 to send y stream i just want something like. 

Client 1 2 3 are connected with SSL to my server program. I just want to send Trough there connections to me that something is going wrong. Like " EY GUYS in the ROOM i just had a problem "

just like an chatserver and client you learned at school :)

Cheers

Comment: Once again, you MUST keep track of the clients that are connected to your server and then the server can send a copy of the same data to every client when needed. Put the clients in a list. Loop through the list. Send the same data to each client in the list. What exactly is unclear about that? That is the ONLY way to do it in TCP. SSL has nothing to do with that logic, but each client would be using its own SSL session to encrypt *whatever* data the server decides to send to that client.